# How to use netplan to connect to EAP wifi

Tags: ubuntu, networking, netplan

I can't find any good guides online on how to connect to eap wifi using netplan. I currently have tried to create a file named `config.yaml` with the following

```
network:

    wifis:

      wlp1s0:

        dhcp4: true

        access-points:

          "IllinoisNet":

            auth:

              key-management: eap

              identity: -----

              password: ----
```

I then do `sudo netplan generate` and `sudo netplan apply`

A couple other questions:
Is identity just username? Because when I log in using a GUI it always asks for a username?
Will that work? Or does the file need to be named a specific way?
Any additional help will be appreciated.

I am running ubuntu 20.04 lts server on a raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0):

Wait nvm I just did `sudo reboot` and it was able to connect to the wifi, I guess identity is username and my formatting was correct and that filename doesn't matter.

Comment: It is making me wait until tmrw then I will, thanks!